# Is this Primefaces bug or Mojarra/MyFaces bug

Tags: jsf, primefaces, myfaces, mojarra

I cannot seems to be able to fire an event when I am within `column` of `dataTable`. Here is my simple demostration

```
<h:form id="form">
    <!--This section of p:tree here seems to be the reason causing the event not fired when click the command button-->
    <p:tree value="#{viewBean.root}" var="node" dynamic="true" cache="false"  
                selectionMode="checkbox"  selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}">  

        <p:ajax event="expand" update=":form:messages" listener="#{viewBean.onNodeExpand}" />  
        <p:ajax event="collapse" update=":form:messages" listener="#{viewBean.onNodeCollapse}" />  
        <p:ajax event="select" update=":form:messages" listener="#{viewBean.onNodeSelect}" />  
        <p:ajax event="unselect" update=":form:messages" listener="#{viewBean.onNodeUnselect}" />  

        <p:treeNode>  
            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />  
        </p:treeNode>  
    </p:tree>
    <h:panelGroup id="mygroup">
            <p:dataTable id="mytable" value="#{viewBean.foodList}" var="item">
                <p:column>
                    #{item}
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:commandButton value="delete" 
                                     action="#{viewBean.delete}"
                                     update=":form:mygroup">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                                     value="#{item}"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

and here is my managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewBean {

    private TreeNode root;  

    private TreeNode selectedNode;  
    private List<String> foodList;

    private String selectedFood;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){

        foodList = new ArrayList<String>();
        foodList.add("Pizza");
        foodList.add("Pasta");
        foodList.add("Hamburger");

        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);  
        TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0", root);  
        TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1", root);  
        TreeNode node2 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 2", root);  

        TreeNode node00 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0", node0);  
        TreeNode node01 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1", node0);  

        TreeNode node10 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0", node1);  
        TreeNode node11 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.1", node1);  

        TreeNode node000 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.0", node00);  
        TreeNode node001 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.1", node00);  
        TreeNode node010 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1.0", node01);  

        TreeNode node100 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0.0", node10);  
    }

    public void delete(){

        foodList.remove(selectedFood);

    }
    //setter and getter

    public void onNodeExpand(NodeExpandEvent event) {  
       FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Expanded", event.getTreeNode().toString());  

       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);  
    }  

    public void onNodeCollapse(NodeCollapseEvent event) {  
       FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Collapsed", event.getTreeNode().toString());  

       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);  
    }  

    public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {  
       FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Selected", event.getTreeNode().toString());  

       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);  
    }  

    public void onNodeUnselect(NodeUnselectEvent event) {  
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Unselected", event.getTreeNode().toString());  

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);  
    }  
}
```

My problem seems to be that the event is not fired, meaning `delete` never get invoked.

I have look around, and know that Mojarra have ton of issues with nested UIData components, so I tried Mojarra 2.1.4, still did not solved the problem. I tried Myfaces 2.1.5, still does not work!!! Is this a Primefaces bugs? I even use `h:panelGroup` as a wrapper for `update` but it still does not work.

**EDIT**: It turn out that the `p:tree` above the `dataTable` is the root cause of the event not fired when clicking the `commandButton`. If I remove the `p:tree` then it work immediately. Note that the `p:tree` itself work great, as I click on the checkout, event fired on my managed bean.

Comment: In the future, please be a bit more specific with regard to "does not work". E.g. "the `selectedFood` is `null` inside the `delete()` method".

Comment: @BalusC: Sorry, I have edit my post to clarify what I mean when i said `does not work`.

Comment: Fine, to avoid red herrings please don't forget to fix your own bug for which I initially posted the answer. You are still not clear on "does not work". What exactly do you mean with "event not fired"? For example, is there no ajax request been sent at all according to Firebug/Chrome or whatever?

Comment: @BalusC: As soon as I add `<p:tree>` back, and run my debugger, when I click the button, it does not get inside my `delete()` method. I am looking firebug to see if any ajax event was being fired at all.

Comment: Shouldn't the `#{treeBean}` be `#{viewBean}`?

Comment: yup, sure is. So silly, of me. Now I got this response `<partial-response><error><error-name>class javax.el.ELException</error-name><error-message><![CDATA[/index.xhtml @15,84 selection="#{viewBean.selectedNode}": Cannot convert [Lorg.primefaces.model.TreeNode;@fd9b4d of type class [Lorg.primefaces.model.TreeNode; to interface org.primefaces.model.TreeNode]]></error-message></error></partial-response>`. I have checked my java code. I `import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;`. Not sure where `Lorg.primefaces.model.TreeNode` come from

Comment: Are you sure that the `<p:tree>` works? This exception suggests that it's expecting a property of `TreeNode[]` instead of `TreeNode` and this in turn suggests that you would have exactly the same problem even when you remove the whole `<p:dataTable>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in your own code.

```
<partial-response>
  <error>
    <error-name>class javax.el.ELException</error-name>
    <error-message><![CDATA[/index.xhtml @15,84 selection="#{viewBean.selectedNode}": Cannot convert [Lorg.primefaces.model.TreeNode;@fd9b4d of type class [Lorg.primefaces.model.TreeNode; to interface org.primefaces.model.TreeNode]]></error-message>
  </error>
</partial-response>
```

The concrete exception message suggests that the `<p:tree selection>` is expected to refer a property of type `TreeNode[]` and not `TreeNode` (note the `[` prefix on the class identifier in the message which indicates an array type). So, fix it accordingly:

```
<p:tree selection="#{treeBean.selectedNodes}">
```

with

```
private TreeNode[] selectedNodes;
```

Regardless, you've both the `<p:tree>` and `<p:dataTable>` inside the one and same "god" form. So any action in either of them will submit everything on the other component as well. If the tree and the table are in no way related to each other, then they should each be placed in its own `<h:form>`. Or, you must add a `process` attribute to the command links/buttons to process only the containing component of interest, e.g. `process="mytable"` on the button inside the table.

Comment: Thank you BalusC. I first have `selectionMode="single"`, then I switch it to `selectionMode="checkbox"`, but I did not realize that I need to use `TreeNode[]`. Thank you very much. One last question, does `Lorg.primefaces.model.TreeNode` mean TreeNode[]?

Comment: No, it identifies an object of type `TreeNode`. The `[Lorg.primefaces.model.TreeNode` identifies an array of objects of type `TreeNode`.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Learning some debugging skill today :)

Comment: See also http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#7028