# JSF2: action and actionListener

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, action, actionlistener

From this answer by BalusC here [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener), `Use actionListener if you want have a hook before the real business action get executed, e.g. to log it, and/or to set an additional property (by <f:setPropertyActionListener>,`. However when I decide to write some code to test this, the result is a bit different. Here is my small code

```
<h:form id="form"> 
   <h:panelGroup id="mygroup">
     <p:dataTable id="mytable" value="#{viewBean.foodList}" var="item">
         <p:column>
             #{item}
         </p:column>
         <p:column>
             <p:commandButton value="delete" 
                        action="#{viewBean.delete}"
                        update=":form:mygroup">
                 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                              value="#{item}"/>
             </p:commandButton>
         </p:column>
      </p:dataTable>
   </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Here is my bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewBean {
    private List<String> foodList;
    private String selectedFood;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){

        foodList = new ArrayList<String>();
        foodList.add("Pizza");
        foodList.add("Pasta");
        foodList.add("Hamburger");
    }

    public void delete(){
        foodList.remove(selectedFood);
    }
    //setter, getter...
}
```

According to BalusC, `actionListener` is **more suitable** here, but my example show **otherwise**.

The above code work great with `action`, but if I switch over to `actionListener`, then it does not quite work. It will take **two clicks** for me to delete an entry of this table using `actionListener`, while if I use `action`, it delete entry every time I click the button. I wonder if any JSF expert out there can help me understand `action` vs `actionListener`

**Note** If I switch to `actionListener`, my `delete` method become `public void delete(ActionEvent actionEvent)`

Comment: Is it specific to primefaces or you get the same with `<h:commandButton>`?

Comment: @mrembisz: I did use `update` of the `p:commandButton`, so I think there is a related to primefaces, but I am not 100% sure. Will try to look deeper.

Comment: @mrembisz: Mr.J4mes did confirm `h:commandButton` shows the same behavior.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're confusing `action` with `actionListener`. The `actionListener` runs always before the `action`. If there are multiple action listeners, then they run in the same order as they have been registered. That's why it doesn't work as expected when you use `actionListener` to call the business action and `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` to set (prepare) a property which is to be used by the business action. This problem was pointed out and fixed in your previous question [Is this Primefaces bug or Mojarra/MyFaces bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660600/is-this-primefaces-bug-or-mojarra-myfaces-bug).

Whatever you have in the `delete()` method is clearly a business action and should be invoked by `action` instead. A business action typically invokes an EJB service and if necessary also sets the final result and/or navigates to a different view.

Answer (score 4):

I tried your example with original JSF's tags `<h:commandButton>` but I also get the same symptom. I believe if you specify `actionListener` attribute and at the same time, declare another listener with `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`, the listener in the attribute `actionListener` will be fired before the other.

**UPDATE**: I test my assumption with the following code:

- Change your `delete` function to this one:

  ```
  public void delete(){
      this.selectedFood = "Chicken";
      //foodList.remove(selectedFood);
  }
  ```
- Add `<h:outputText id="food" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}" />` inside `<h:panelGroup id="mygroup">`.

You will see that the outputText is always `Chicken`.

Comment: I actually gradually drifted to that conclusion as well. I realized that `selectedFood` is null when the `delete` method get invoke. Does that mean what `BalusC` said is wrong? `ohh noooo!!!!!!!!!!!!!`

Comment: He's not wrong :P. I think you mis-understood his saying. He was trying to explain the different usages of `action` and `actionListener`. `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` is one kind of `actionListener` and he mentioned it to show how you can `set an additional property` in his example. In general, `actionListener` always get fired before `action`. That's why it always work with `action`.

Comment: he said to use `actionListener if you want have a hook before the real business action get executed`. So is `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` not the `hook` before business action which is `delete`? When I read that sentence, I thought he mean `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` will get executed before `delete`

Comment: The action he mentioned in `a hook before the real business action` is your `delete` method only if it is declared like this `action="#{viewBean.delete}"`. If you declared it with `actionListener`, it became a listener which is no longer a `real business action`.